# CentOS 7/CloudLinux yum: Mass of Packages Can't Update

Tags: centos, yum, update, cloudlinux

I run *yum update* and it tells me A LOT of packages need updating. I can't even fit it all into this post. These are the errors I get near the end...

```
---> Package python-magic.noarch 0:5.11-33.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libX11-devel-1.6.3-2.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libX11 = 1.6.3-2.el7
           Removing: libX11-1.6.3-2.el7.i686 (@cloudlinux-base)
               libX11 = 1.6.3-2.el7
           Updated By: libX11-1.6.3-3.el7.i686 (cloudlinux-base)
               libX11 = 1.6.3-3.el7
Error: Package: tkinter-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: python = 2.7.5-34.el7
           Removing: python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python = 2.7.5-34.el7
           Updated By: python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               python = 2.7.5-48.el7
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Removing: php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Updated By: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux
Error: Package: php-devel-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Removing: php-cli-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Updated By: php-cli-5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux
Error: Package: python-devel-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-34.el7
           Removing: python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-34.el7
           Updated By: python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               python(x86-64) = 2.7.5-48.el7
Error: Package: krb5-devel-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libkadm5srv_mit.so.9()(64bit)
           Removing: krb5-libs-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
               libkadm5srv_mit.so.9()(64bit)
           Updated By: krb5-libs-1.14.1-27.el7_3.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               Not found
Error: Package: php-xmlrpc-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Removing: php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Updated By: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux
Error: Package: expat-devel-2.1.0-8.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: expat = 2.1.0-8.el7
           Removing: expat-2.1.0-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               expat = 2.1.0-8.el7
           Updated By: expat-2.1.0-10.el7_3.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               expat = 2.1.0-10.el7_3
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-devel-5.5.47-1.el7_2.cloudlinux.2.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2.cloudlinux.2
           Removing: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.47-1.el7_2.cloudlinux.2.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2.cloudlinux.2
           Updated By: 2:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 2:5.5.52-1.el7.cloudlinux
Error: Package: krb5-devel-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.13.2-12.el7_2
           Removing: krb5-libs-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.13.2-12.el7_2
           Updated By: krb5-libs-1.14.1-27.el7_3.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.14.1-27.el7_3
Error: Package: python-tools-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: python = 2.7.5-34.el7
           Removing: python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python = 2.7.5-34.el7
           Updated By: python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               python = 2.7.5-48.el7
Error: Package: interworx-5.1.41-1262.iworx.noarch (@interworx-release-noarch)
           Requires: perl(stat.pl)
           Removing: 4:perl-5.16.3-286.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               perl(stat.pl)
           Updated By: 4:perl-5.16.3-291.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               Not found
Error: Package: openldap-devel-2.4.40-9.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: openldap(x86-64) = 2.4.40-9.el7_2
           Removing: openldap-2.4.40-9.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
               openldap(x86-64) = 2.4.40-9.el7_2
           Updated By: openldap-2.4.40-13.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               openldap(x86-64) = 2.4.40-13.el7
Error: Package: libcom_err-devel-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-7.el7
           Removing: libcom_err-1.42.9-7.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-7.el7
           Updated By: libcom_err-1.42.9-9.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               libcom_err(x86-64) = 1.42.9-9.el7
Error: Package: krb5-devel-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: libkadm5clnt_mit.so.8()(64bit)
           Removing: krb5-libs-1.13.2-12.el7_2.x86_64 (@updates)
               libkadm5clnt_mit.so.8()(64bit)
           Updated By: krb5-libs-1.14.1-27.el7_3.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               Not found
Error: Package: php-intl-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Removing: php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Updated By: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux
Error: Package: liblve-devel-1.4-1.4.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: liblve = 1.4-1.4.el7.cloudlinux
           Removing: liblve-1.4-1.4.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               liblve = 1.4-1.4.el7.cloudlinux
           Updated By: liblve-1.4-1.13.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               liblve = 1.4-1.13.el7.cloudlinux
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Removing: php-pdo-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.cloudlinux
           Updated By: php-pdo-5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7.cloudlinux
Error: Package: 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5
           Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64 (@updates)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5
           Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-60.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-60.el7
Error: Package: freetype-demos-2.4.11-11.el7.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: freetype = 2.4.11-11.el7
           Removing: freetype-2.4.11-11.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               freetype = 2.4.11-11.el7
           Updated By: freetype-2.4.11-12.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               freetype = 2.4.11-12.el7
Error: Package: libffi-devel-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: libffi = 3.0.13-16.el7
           Removing: libffi-3.0.13-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libffi = 3.0.13-16.el7
           Updated By: libffi-3.0.13-18.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               libffi = 3.0.13-18.el7
Error: Package: fontconfig-devel-2.10.95-7.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.10.95-7.el7
           Removing: fontconfig-2.10.95-7.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.10.95-7.el7
           Updated By: fontconfig-2.10.95-10.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               fontconfig(x86-64) = 2.10.95-10.el7
Error: Package: libcurl-devel-7.29.0-25.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: libcurl = 7.29.0-25.el7.cloudlinux
           Removing: libcurl-7.29.0-25.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               libcurl = 7.29.0-25.el7.cloudlinux
           Updated By: libcurl-7.29.0-35.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               libcurl = 7.29.0-35.el7.cloudlinux
Error: Package: iptables-services-1.4.21-16.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
           Requires: iptables = 1.4.21-16.el7.cloudlinux
           Removing: iptables-1.4.21-16.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (@cloudlinux-x86_64-server-7)
               iptables = 1.4.21-16.el7.cloudlinux
           Updated By: iptables-1.4.21-17.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               iptables = 1.4.21-17.el7.cloudlinux
Error: Package: libsepol-devel-2.1.9-3.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libsepol = 2.1.9-3.el7
           Removing: libsepol-2.1.9-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libsepol = 2.1.9-3.el7
           Updated By: libsepol-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               libsepol = 2.5-6.el7
Error: Package: libselinux-devel-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: libselinux = 2.2.2-6.el7
           Removing: libselinux-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               libselinux = 2.2.2-6.el7
           Updated By: libselinux-2.5-6.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               libselinux = 2.5-6.el7
Error: Package: avahi-autoipd-0.6.31-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 (@updates)
           Requires: avahi-libs = 0.6.31-15.el7_2.1
           Removing: avahi-libs-0.6.31-15.el7_2.1.x86_64 (@updates)
               avahi-libs = 0.6.31-15.el7_2.1
           Updated By: avahi-libs-0.6.31-17.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               avahi-libs = 0.6.31-17.el7
Error: Package: freetype-devel-2.4.11-11.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: freetype = 2.4.11-11.el7
           Removing: freetype-2.4.11-11.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               freetype = 2.4.11-11.el7
           Updated By: freetype-2.4.11-12.el7.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               freetype = 2.4.11-12.el7
Error: Package: abrt-retrace-client-2.1.11-36.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: abrt = 2.1.11-36.el7.centos
           Removing: abrt-2.1.11-36.el7.centos.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               abrt = 2.1.11-36.el7.centos
           Updated By: abrt-2.1.11-45.el7.cloudlinux.x86_64 (cloudlinux-base)
               abrt = 2.1.11-45.el7.cloudlinux
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've tried...

yum update --skip-broken

rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

yum clean all

rpmdb --rebuilddb

package-cleanup --dupes

package-cleanup --cleandupes

yum-complete-transaction

yum distro-sync

And *yum update* still won't work. Don't know what to do.

Comment: It looks like you have some conflicting repos there.

Comment: I think I got it. Waiting for update to finish to be sure.